# Increasing number of "Device not compatible" issues in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, apk

Our app has been available for over 4 years without this sort of issue, but within the past month we have a variety of users emailing us to say that when they try to download the app it says "Device not compatible" in Google Play.

The changes we made during this period were the addition of In-App purchasing into the app.

[image: Here is an image of the support and features listed for this APK in Google Play Developer Console]

Here are some questions I was asking users who reported it.

User 1:

1. What version of Android are you running? Android 5.1
2. What type of device? Motorola Droid Turbo
3. Do you have a credit card already associated with Google Play? Yes, and a "google rewards" that I use to pay for most google items.
4. Which carrier are you using? Verizon
5. Which country are you in? IL, USA

User 2:

1. What version of Android are you running? Android 5.0
2. What type of device? Samsung Galaxy S5
3. Do you have a credit card already associated with Google Play? No, I don't have a credit card associated yet
4. Which carrier are you using? Viva
5. Which country are you in? Kuwait

User 3:

1. What version of Android are you running? Android 5.0
2. What type of device? Samsung S5
3. Do you have a credit card already associated with Google Play? Yes
4. Which carrier are you using? Verizon
5. Which country are you in? U.S.

We have thousands of users with the same devices though which also adds to the oddness of this.

Has anyone else experienced anything similar or found a solution?

Comment: I think this documentation [Filters on Google Play](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html) is worth looking at for this particular problem especially that it is occuring only with certain devices. In enabling the In-app billing maybe some settings changed in your Google Play that disabled installation with certain hardware components. See [Controlling Your App's Availability for Business Reasons](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html#filtering)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and got success in **Motorol Droid Turbo** and many other **samsung** devices. Google play store reads manifest file and do filteration and shows supported devices in developers console(you can preview type of devices that your app supports before publishing).

Please check below tags in your manifest file which may cause the device compatible issues for your app:

**< compatible-screens>**

If you have declared **< compatible screen >** tag, please dont use it, as it only covers a range of devices which you include in **< compatible-screens >** tag.

**< supports-screens >**

If your app will cover all devices you dont have to put this tag in your manifest file.

**< uses-feature >**

This is very important tag which will make your app compatible for most of the devices present in the Google play store. You can mention all the features that are not required by your application as below:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
```

Note: required= false means this features in not mandatory for your application. So as many features that are not required by your application please mention in the manifest file required false. i.e those features will be excluded from the Google play store filter process.